# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have a sqlite problem with phonegap 1.6.1.
The first query tag returns fine, however the callback barfs with **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined** . 
jquery wont refresh the list properly because of the js error. As far as I can see the call and callback have the correct syntax

anybody experienced a similar problem?

```
/* MY JUICES*/
function queryMyJuices(tx) {
tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM MYJUICE',
                [], queryMJSuccess, errorCB);
}


function queryMJSuccess(tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    $("ul#myjuices")
            .append(
                    '<li id=' 
                            + results.rows.item(i).id
                            + ' " >'
                            + results.rows.item(i).name
                            + ' </a><a rel="delete"
data-rel="dialog" href="#two">Delete</a></li>');

} $('ul#myjuices').listview('refresh');

}
/* MY JUICES*/
```

Comment: I would recommend testing in Chrome so that you get a better debug console. The SQL functions are part of the HTML5 spec so you should still have access to them. Put a breakpoint in your callback and check what values are coming through.